# How would you explain this cache behavior? Number of cache misses looks strange

Tags: caching, perf

I observed a strange number of cache misses that I cannot explain properly while examining cache behavior. Here is my C code:

```
typedef struct sa_1
{
    double f1;
}sa_1;

double foo (double arg)
{
    static unsigned long counter = 0;
    ++counter;
    if (arg >= 0)
    {
        return arg;
    }
    else
    {
        return -arg;
    }
}

//in main () :
    sa_1* data_1 = (sa_1*)malloc (arrayLength * sizeof (sa_1)); //arrayLength = 100000000
    if (data_1 == NULL)
    {
        printf ("malloc fail\n");
    }
    printf ("data_1 addr: %p\n", data_1);

    for (l = 0; l < loopCount; l++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            foo (data_1[i].f1);
        }
    }
    free (data_1);
```

Platform：

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz (L1 cache size 32KB with line size 64B)
OS:  Linux version 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
GCC: 4.8.5
```

Compiler Options: -O0

Suppose the addr returned by malloc () is 64B aligned, so that every eight elements of array pointed by data_1 form a cacheline (8*8 = 64). Therefore each sequential traversal incurs (1*10^8/8 = 12.5) million times of cache miss. On my platform malloc () is 16B aligned, so the estimation above should not go far. Hence the total number of cache misses produced by this program should be around (loopCount*12.5 million). But...

Monitor the number of cache misses using "perf stat -e L1-dcache-load-misses" gives the following result
loopCount=1:

```
        25,437,474      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       0.500455054 seconds time elapsed
```

loopCount=2:

```
        37,931,042      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       0.819157041 seconds time elapsed
```

loopCount=3:

```
        50,589,210      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       1.129980781 seconds time elapsed
```

The results of different runs didn't differ much. Seems like the total number of cache misses obeys ((loopCount+1)*12.5 million).

Moving the malloc-free call into outer layer for-loop:

```
//in main () :
    for (l = 0; l < loopCount; l++)
    {
        sa_1* data_1 = (sa_1*)malloc (arrayLength * sizeof (sa_1)); //arrayLength = 100000000
        if (data_1 == NULL)
        {
            printf ("malloc fail\n");
        }
        printf ("data_1 addr: %p\n", data_1);

        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            foo (data_1[i].f1);
        }
    
        free (data_1);
    }
```

This gives:
loopCount=1:

```
        25,428,129      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       0.476362859 seconds time elapsed
```

loopCount=2:

```
        25,428,129      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       0.476362859 seconds time elapsed
```

loopCount=3:

```
        76,460,069      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       

       1.411193877 seconds time elapsed
```

Something like ((loopCount*2)*12.5 million). I do my best to make 2 guesses based on these results: 1. The malloc () implementation I used performs initialization for the memory it allocated, so each malloc () call produce an extra traversal to data_1 array, incurring 12.5 million misses each time. 2. Caching is disabled at the first time a memory line is accessed. Newly malloced memory is untouched, therefore first traversal incurs 2*12.5 million instead of 1*1.25 million.

Experiment to disprove (1.): Simply set loopCount=0 in the first program, perf report only 10000~20000 misses in a run.

For (2.), I failed to come up with a verification scheme, or to find relative materials. Any advice?

Comment: I performed these test on a different platform with CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz, the strange thing vanished. This makes (2.) look more promising.

Comment: On Linux, glibc malloc will use `mmap` for large allocations, so the memory is zero-initialized by the kernel.  (And lazily copy-on-write allocated; read-only access will see all the pages mapped to the same physical page of zeros, so you can get cache hits but TLB misses.  If it uses transparent hugepages, it might be a shared 2M page, though, so you'd get L1 and L2 misses, only L3 hits.)  `free` of big allocation gives them back to the kernel right away (`munmap`), so yes it is different from reusing the same allocation.  I"m not sure this fully explains what you're seeing, though.